# getting error pls help

Tags: visualforce, controller

I had developed a code when I am adding **save** code I am getting an error

> **"Error: Unknown method 'Hospitalcntlr1.save()' "**

In the code I want to add all the details of patient in a tabular format once added but it is not coming in the form.

My Visualforce page:

```
    <apex:page controller="Hospitalcntlr1">
      <apex:Form >
       <apex:pageBlock >        
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Department">
           <apex:inputField value="{!Dept.Name}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Dept.Department_Number__c}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Dept.Dept_Doctor__c}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Dept.DoctorId__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Patient">
           <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.Name}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.patientinfo__c}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.PatientId__c}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.Patient_Joining_Date__c}"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.Patient_Out_Date__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!patntlist}" var="pat">
                <apex:column value="{!pat.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pat.patientinfo__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pat.PatientId__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pat.Patient_Joining_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pat.Patient_Out_Date__c}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton  action="{!save}" value="{!save}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>    
             </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:Form>
    </apex:page>
```

Apex class is:

```
    public with sharing class Hospitalcntlr1 {
       Public Department__c dept{get;set;}
       Public Patient__c patnt{get;set;}
       public list<Patient__c> patntlist{get;set;}
       public Hospitalcntlr1()
       {
          String ids=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
           patntlist=[select id, name,patientinfo__c,Patient_Joining_Date__c,Patient_Out_Date__c,Department__C,PatientId__c from patient__c where id=:ids limit 1 ];
          for(Patient__C pet:patntlist)
            {
               dept=[select id,name,Department_Number__c,Dept_Doctor__c,Doctorid__C from Department__c where id=:pet.Department__C];
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please don't edit your question to ask something different; instead, create a new question. Otherwise all context is lost and it discourages users from answering.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `Save` action on VF page but not define it on controller So define a method in APEX as you use a Custom controller so use the code snippet like this in your controller:

```
 public with sharing class Hospitalcntlr1 {
   Public Department__c dept{get;set;}
   Public Patient__c patnt{get;set;}
   public list<Patient__c> patntlist{get;set;}
   public Hospitalcntlr1()
   {
      patnt=new patient();
      String ids=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
       patntlist=[select id, name,patientinfo__c,Patient_Joining_Date__c,Patient_Out_Date__c,Department__C,PatientId__c from patient__c where id=:ids limit 1 ];
      for(Patient__C pet:patntlist)
        {
           dept=[select id,name,Department_Number__c,Dept_Doctor__c,Doctorid__C from Department__c where id=:pet.Department__C];
        }
    }  
public void Save(){
   patnt.Name=patnt.Name;
   patnt.Patientinfo__c=patnt.Patientinfo__c;
   patnt.Patientid__c=patnt.Patientid__c;
   patnt.Department__c=patnt.Department__c;
   patnt.Patient_Joining_Date__c=patnt.Patient_Joining_Date__c;
   patnt.Patient_out_Date__c=patnt.Patient_out_Date__c;
   insert patnt;
   patnt=new patnt();
 }          
}
```

and add a line in VF page

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!patnt.Department__c}"/>
```

and `CommantButton` line Should be

```
<apex:Commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `value` attribute should be "Save", not "{!save}". When you use a value attribute with a merge field, it expects a function called `getSave`. I presume that this wasn't your intent.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i had written a code to get a table in same page but table is not displaying can u please help me

Comment: I'm not sure what "table" you are referring to, as it's not in the question.

Comment: is my apex class i am refering to patntlist
    But i am unable to display form in my table

Comment: `patntlist` should be populated in the constructor.

Comment: Hi user4507, it seems you are asking a separate question to the original question. Please create a new question with the problem you are now trying to solve. Thanks